# Graph Theory book with lots of Named Graphs/ Graph Families

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I'm doing a research about an operation on graphs and I am now in the point where I want to apply it to some named graphs or to some of the graph families like paths, cycles, wheels, etc. I am wondering if there is a book or a paper that contains different named graphs and graph families. Currently I have the following references:

[mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/SimpleGraphs.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/SimpleGraphs.html)

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_named_graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_named_graphs)

[altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/NamedGraphs.pdf](http://altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/NamedGraphs.pdf)

[graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html](http://graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html)

What I am looking for is like an encyclopedia of graphs where I can look at the graph and its properties. I'm looking for graph families where you can easily get the next graph (ex.paths, cycles). My above references are webpages and I'm wondering if there might be a book containing these things. Well any additional resources of any form will be very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429184/looking-for-a-resource-to-identify-name-a-given-graph/1432317#1432317

Answer (score 8):

I'm a former editor of MathWorld, and I pretty much got my hands on every available graph theory book, and looked through all the graph theory journals.

In GraphData[], Mathematica has 6744 named graphs at the moment, with up to 457 calculated or researched properties for each one.

There isn't a book I'd recommend, but the book I got the most graphs out of was *Distance-Regular Graphs* by [Andries E. Brouwer](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/).

Answer (score 5):

There is Read and Wilson "An Atlas of Graphs", but you will want to find a copy in a library. I think most of these graphs have been built into sage, so there is free and convenient access to them.

Answer (score 4):

Recently, I also needed such a reference. The [House of Graphs](http://hog.grinvin.org/) proved to be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards this page... if I may ask, what was your interest?

Comment: @draks... I am sorry, I completely forgot. I just remembered the reference as it came handy. It probably had to do with verifying an social networks result on small graphs.

Comment: House of Graphs has recently moved. The updated link is https://houseofgraphs.org/